# Why does Snowflake not report ambiguous column references for USING joins

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given this query snowflake returns a result set of `2`, arbitrarily resolving `y` to the table `T`,

```sql
select y
from (select 1 x, 2 y) T
join (select 1 x, 3 y) T1 using (x)
```

while at the same time returning an ambiguous column error when using a qualified join instead:

```sql
select y
from (select 1 x, 2 y) T
join (select 1 x, 3 y) T1 on T.x = T1.x
```

What's the set of rules that determine whether a column reference is ambiguous in Snowflake SQL? Postgres considers both of these queries ambiguous.

Comment: Seems like a bug

Comment: Why not just write explicit joins and then there would be no confusion or need to know how a specific DBMS handles the USING join?

Comment: @NickW It's because I'm writing a type checker/linter for different SQL dialects, so it's not my code I'm analysing.

Secondly, why is the USING join special? If I "just" write explicit joins, do I not need to know how a specific DBMS handles it?

And third, if you'd rather answer a different question than the one asked, maybe just don't bother commenting on it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just an observation. It seems the column is chosen depending on order of join(left-to-right):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T(x INT, y INT) AS select 1, 2 UNION SELECT 10, 20;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T1(x INT, y INT) AS select 1, 3 UNION SELECT 10, 30;

-- disabling cache
ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT=FALSE;
```

Query profile:

```
explain using tabular
select y
from T
join T1 using (x);
```

Output:

[image]

Swapped join order:

```
explain using tabular
select y
from T1
join T using (x);
```

Output:

[image]